# Is there any command can be used to find all directories with header (.h or .hpp) files in?

Tags: linux, gcc, directory, header-files

I want to find these directories to include in my GCC header paths. I know that we can use `find -type d -name 'include'` to find all include directories, however, some header files are not in directories called include. Is there any fancy command that can bed used to solve the question?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -exec dirname {} + | uniq
```

This will search for

- all files (`-type f`)
- that end in `.h` or `.hpp` (`-name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp"`),
- get the directory name of each (`-exec dirname {} +`)
- and remove duplicates (`uniq`)

Comment: That's what I need, great thanks!

Comment: I find this way takes a lot of time, and I'm wondering if I can `find . -type d -exec $(some command to list the filenames in the directory) | grep '.*\.h'`  to solve the problem.

Comment: I doubt that would be faster since that lists even more files (and then skips some of them in the output). You could split it into stages where you first only search for the files, save the list into a file and then do the filtering afterwards